# Converting string to date time in powershell

Tags: string, powershell, datetime

I am trying to parse filenames (strings) and convert them to dates in powershell using the following line:

```
([datetime]::ParseExact($DirName.BaseName,'yyyyMMdd',$null)
```

The problem is, not all of the folders in that directory following that naming convention.  How would I first test to see if the folder fits the naming convention and if it does, convert it to a date time object?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use RegEx. That way you could detect different patterns and act on them with specific solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't bother checking first. Just put the call in a `try..catch` block. I would recommend using [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) rather than `$null`, though.

```
$culture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture
try {
  [datetime]::ParseExact($DirName.BaseName, 'yyyyMMdd', $culture)
} catch {
  # not a valid date
}
```